# Python to slack text Integration

Tags: python, python-requests, slack

```
def send_message_to_slack(text):
    from urllib3 import request
    from urllib3 import parse
    import json

    post = {"text": "{0}".format(text)}

    try:
        json_data = json.dumps(post)
        req = request.Request("https://hooks.slack.com/services/web-hook",
        data=json_data.encode('ascii'),
        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
        resp = request.urlopen(req)
    except Exception as em:
        print("EXCEPTION: " + str(em))

send_message_to_slack('This message is from Python program')
```

The above program prompts the error of

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "slacktext.py", line 17, in <module>
    send_message_to_slack('This message is from Python program')
  File "slacktext.py", line 3, in send_message_to_slack
    from urllib3 import parse
ImportError: cannot import name 'parse'
```

I have installed the urllib3 but can't import parse and request

Comment: `from urllib import parse`; you drop the 3 for `parse` [docs](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html)

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "slacktext.py", line 17, in <module>
    send_message_to_slack('This message is from Python program')
  File "slacktext.py", line 3, in send_message_to_slack
    from urllib3 import parse3
ImportError: cannot import name 'parse3'
` 
still the same error

Comment: Your import line should be `from urllib import parse` not `from urllib3 import parse` nor `from urllib3 import parse3`. Have a look at the examples in the docs above.

Comment: Solves my problem. Thank you